# How call python function from C in MicroPython

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, micropython

I have a function in my C-code and I want to call a python function that has been written in python script. Is it possible in MicroPython? If yes, how can I do it?

My C-Code Function:

```
float bar_C_Fun(int i, int j){
 return foo_Py_Fun(I,j);
 }
```

My Python-Code Function:

```
def  foo_Py_Fun(i , j):
  return i/j
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone already asked this 4 years ago in another forum

The thread: https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?t=3761

The reply:

> Re: How to call C function in python code
>
> Post by dhylands » Wed Sep 06, 2017 10:44 pm
> You need to create a C module which exports functions which are callable from python.
>
> See this thread here: https://forum.micropython.org/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=2861&p=19206#p19206
> Dave Hylands